# Fetch product category matching the product ID

Tags: scrapy

I have created a keywords.csv file in my resource folder in order to automatically fetch the data from all the products listed in there. This works perfectly. The first column of the .csv-file is named "keywords". The keywords are based on a unique number representing the product category (i.e., high pressure washer, floor cleaner, ...). I am using this number to adjust the API URL where I am fetching all the data from.

I would like to print out the product category. Because there is no product category defined in the API where I am fetching the data from, I would like to print out the second column of my .csv-file, being "keywordtype". The "keywordtype" should be printed to the products with the same "keyword".

Secondly, I've been googling around but couldn't find a solution for replacing multiple characters in one string. Is there a way of making some sort of dictionairy so that "\u00e9" gets replaced with "é", "\u00b2" with "²", etc. I tried using .replace('text','') and .split(), but for multiple characters this isn't sufficient.

**What I tried**

I tried calling the "keywordtype" in the def parse(self, response):, but I don't know how to make it check which keyword is being used. Therefore it keeps printing the same "keywordtype" over and over again.

```
...
    def parse(self, response):
    #Calling the "category" from the keywords.csv file -- THIS IS NOT WORKING
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                category=keyword["keywordtype"]

...
```

**FULL CODE** #1

**Spider.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 12 22:44:35 2019

@author: bergs
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from krc.items import KrcItem
import json
import os
import csv
import time
import datetime

class KRCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "krc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["kaercher.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL']

    def start_requests(self):
        """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                search_text=keyword["keyword"]
                category = keyword["keywordtype"]
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(
                    search_text)
                # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text, "category": category}) 

    def parse(self, response):
        category = response.meta["category"]

        current_page = response.meta.get("page", 1)
        next_page = current_page + 1

        #Printing the timestamp when fetching the data, using default timezone from the requesting machine
        ts = time.time()
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

        #Defining the items
        item = KrcItem()
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for company in data.get('products', []):
            item["productid"] = company["id"]
            item["category"] = category
            item["name"] = company["name"]
            item["description"] = company["description"]
            item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"].replace("\u20ac","").strip()
            item["timestamp"] = timestamp
            yield item

        #Checking whether "isTruncated" is true (boolean), if so, next page will be triggered
        if data["isTruncated"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'page': next_page},
            )
```

**FULL CODE** #2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 12 22:44:35 2019

@author: bergs
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from krc.items import KrcItem
import json
import os
import csv
import time
import datetime

class KRCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "krc_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["kaercher.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL']

    def start_requests(self):
        """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
            for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
                search_text = keyword["keyword"]
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(
                    search_text)
                # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text}) 

    def parse(self, response):
        current_page = response.meta.get("page", 1)
        next_page = current_page + 1

        #Printing the timestamp when fetching the data, using default timezone from the requesting machine
        ts = time.time()
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

        #Defining the items
        item = KrcItem()
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for company in data.get('products', []):
            item["productid"] = company["id"]
            item["category"] = company["url"].split('/')[-2].replace('-',' ')
            item["name"] = company["name"]
            item["description"] = company["description"]
            item["price"] = company["priceFormatted"].replace("\u20ac","").strip()
            item["timestamp"] = timestamp
            yield item

        #Checking whether "isTruncated" is true (boolean), if so, next page will be triggered
        if data["isTruncated"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'page': next_page},
            )
```

**Keywords.csv**

```
keyword,keywordtype
20035386,Hogedrukreiniger
20035424,Window Vacs
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class KrcItem(scrapy.Item):
    productid=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    producttype=scrapy.Field()
    timestamp=scrapy.Field()
    category=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**Results.json #1**

```
[
{"productid": 10491477, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "WV 6 + KV 4(wit)", "description": "De vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 inclusief elektrische bevochtiging, vibratie, tweede wisdoek en meer accessoires maakt het vuil los - en de Window Vac WV 6 zuigt het achterblijvende water af.", "price": "169,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10491478, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "WV 6 + KV 4", "description": "Schone vensters in een handomdraai: met de vibrerende Window Vac KV 4 inclusief elektrische watervoorziening en vibratie maakt u het vuil eerst los en daarna zuigt u met de Window Vac WV 6 het vuile water af.", "price": "159,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10491479, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "WV 6 Plus (wit)", "description": "In een set met 2 wisdoeken voor binnen en buiten, sproeiflacon, reinigingsmiddel en vuilkrabber: de Window Vac WV 6 Premium met innovatieve zuigstrip is nog flexibeler in gebruik.", "price": "109,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10491480, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "WV 6 Plus", "description": "Met innovatieve striptechnologie en nog flexibeler in gebruik: de Window Vac WV 6 Plus voor streepvrij schone vensters in een mum van tijd.", "price": "99,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10491481, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "WV 2 + KV4 (wit)", "description": "Sterk duo voor streepvrij schone vensters: de vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 inclusief elektrische bevochtiging, vibratie, tweede wisdoek en meer extra's, en de Window Vac WV 2.", "price": "139,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10491482, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "WV 2 + KV 4", "description": "Voor moeiteloos ramen lappen: de vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 inclusief elektrische watervoorziening en trilfunctie maakt het vuil los - en de Window Vac WV 2 zuigt het vuile water af.", "price": "129,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10475755, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "KV 4 Premium", "description": "Inclusief tweede wisdoek: de Window Vac KV 4 met elektrische watervoorziening en ondersteunende trilfunctie maakt het vuil moeiteloos los van alle gladde oppervlakken.", "price": "89,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10475756, "category": "Window Vacs", "name": "KV 4", "description": "De vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 maakt vuil moeiteloos los van gladde oppervlakken. Door het elektrisch aangebrachte water en de trillingen wordt handmatig schrobben overbodig.", "price": "79,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10461927, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 7 Premium Full Control Plus Home", "description": "Inclusief slanghaspel en Home Kit: de K 7 Premium Full Control Plus Home. U kunt de juiste druk instellen met de +/- knoppen en de LCD-scherm op het hogedrukpistool van de hogedrukreiniger.", "price": "699,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10453128, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 7 Premium Full Control Plus", "description": "Inclusief slanghaspel: de K 7 Premium Full Control Plus. U kunt de juiste druk instellen met de +/- knoppen en het LCD-scherm op het hogedrukpistool van de hogedrukreiniger.", "price": "639,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10461929, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 7 Full Control Plus Home", "description": "De ideale hogedrukreiniger voor regelmatig gebruik op hardnekkig vuil. K 7 Full Control Plus Home met Home Kit en hogedrukpistool inclusief +/- knoppen voor drukregeling en LCD-scherm.", "price": "639,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10442692, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 7 Full Control Plus", "description": "De K 7 Full Control Plus hogedrukreiniger van K\u00e4rcher inclusief hogedrukpistool met drukregeling en dosering van reinigingsmiddel met een druk op de knop, en een LCD-scherm waarop de druk wordt weergegeven.", "price": "579,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10462452, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 5 Premium Full Control Plus Home", "description": "K 5 Premium Full Control Plus Home hogedrukreiniger met +/- knoppen voor drukregeling en LCD-scherm op het hogedrukpistool. Inclusief Home Kit, 3-in-1 Multi Jet spuitlans en slanghaspel.", "price": "499,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10442700, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 5 Premium Full Control Plus", "description": "Voor regelmatig verwijderen van matige verontreiniging op auto's, stenen muren en fietsen. K 5 Premium Full Control Plus hogedrukreiniger inclusief hogedrukpistool met +/- knoppen voor drukregeling en LCD-scherm.", "price": "449,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10430946, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 5 Full Control", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool - voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Ideaal voor regelmatig gebruik op matige verontreiniging. Oppervlakteprestatie van 40 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "379,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"},
{"productid": 10441978, "category": "Hogedrukreiniger", "name": "K 4 Premium Full Control Home", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool \u2013 voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Inclusief slanghaspel en Home Kit. Ideaal voor een gemiddelde vervuilingsgraad. Oppervlakteprestatie van 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "369,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 15:53:30"}
]
```

**Results.json #2**

```
[
{"productid": 10461927, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 7 Premium Full Control Plus Home", "description": "Inclusief slanghaspel en Home Kit: de K 7 Premium Full Control Plus Home. U kunt de juiste druk instellen met de +/- knoppen en de LCD-scherm op het hogedrukpistool van de hogedrukreiniger.", "price": "699,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10453128, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 7 Premium Full Control Plus", "description": "Inclusief slanghaspel: de K 7 Premium Full Control Plus. U kunt de juiste druk instellen met de +/- knoppen en het LCD-scherm op het hogedrukpistool van de hogedrukreiniger.", "price": "639,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10461929, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 7 Full Control Plus Home", "description": "De ideale hogedrukreiniger voor regelmatig gebruik op hardnekkig vuil. K 7 Full Control Plus Home met Home Kit en hogedrukpistool inclusief +/- knoppen voor drukregeling en LCD-scherm.", "price": "639,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10442692, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 7 Full Control Plus", "description": "De K 7 Full Control Plus hogedrukreiniger van K\u00e4rcher inclusief hogedrukpistool met drukregeling en dosering van reinigingsmiddel met een druk op de knop, en een LCD-scherm waarop de druk wordt weergegeven.", "price": "579,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10462452, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 5 Premium Full Control Plus Home", "description": "K 5 Premium Full Control Plus Home hogedrukreiniger met +/- knoppen voor drukregeling en LCD-scherm op het hogedrukpistool. Inclusief Home Kit, 3-in-1 Multi Jet spuitlans en slanghaspel.", "price": "499,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10442700, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 5 Premium Full Control Plus", "description": "Voor regelmatig verwijderen van matige verontreiniging op auto's, stenen muren en fietsen. K 5 Premium Full Control Plus hogedrukreiniger inclusief hogedrukpistool met +/- knoppen voor drukregeling en LCD-scherm.", "price": "449,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10430946, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 5 Full Control", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool - voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Ideaal voor regelmatig gebruik op matige verontreiniging. Oppervlakteprestatie van 40 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "379,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10441978, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 4 Premium Full Control Home", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool \u2013 voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Inclusief slanghaspel en Home Kit. Ideaal voor een gemiddelde vervuilingsgraad. Oppervlakteprestatie van 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "369,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10491477, "category": "window vacs", "name": "WV 6 + KV 4(wit)", "description": "De vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 inclusief elektrische bevochtiging, vibratie, tweede wisdoek en meer accessoires maakt het vuil los - en de Window Vac WV 6 zuigt het achterblijvende water af.", "price": "169,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10491478, "category": "window vacs", "name": "WV 6 + KV 4", "description": "Schone vensters in een handomdraai: met de vibrerende Window Vac KV 4 inclusief elektrische watervoorziening en vibratie maakt u het vuil eerst los en daarna zuigt u met de Window Vac WV 6 het vuile water af.", "price": "159,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10491479, "category": "window vacs", "name": "WV 6 Plus (wit)", "description": "In een set met 2 wisdoeken voor binnen en buiten, sproeiflacon, reinigingsmiddel en vuilkrabber: de Window Vac WV 6 Premium met innovatieve zuigstrip is nog flexibeler in gebruik.", "price": "109,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10491480, "category": "window vacs", "name": "WV 6 Plus", "description": "Met innovatieve striptechnologie en nog flexibeler in gebruik: de Window Vac WV 6 Plus voor streepvrij schone vensters in een mum van tijd.", "price": "99,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10491481, "category": "window vacs", "name": "WV 2 + KV4 (wit)", "description": "Sterk duo voor streepvrij schone vensters: de vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 inclusief elektrische bevochtiging, vibratie, tweede wisdoek en meer extra's, en de Window Vac WV 2.", "price": "139,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10491482, "category": "window vacs", "name": "WV 2 + KV 4", "description": "Voor moeiteloos ramen lappen: de vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 inclusief elektrische watervoorziening en trilfunctie maakt het vuil los - en de Window Vac WV 2 zuigt het vuile water af.", "price": "129,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10475755, "category": "window vacs", "name": "KV 4 Premium", "description": "Inclusief tweede wisdoek: de Window Vac KV 4 met elektrische watervoorziening en ondersteunende trilfunctie maakt het vuil moeiteloos los van alle gladde oppervlakken.", "price": "89,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10475756, "category": "window vacs", "name": "KV 4", "description": "De vibrerende accu-wisser KV 4 maakt vuil moeiteloos los van gladde oppervlakken. Door het elektrisch aangebrachte water en de trillingen wordt handmatig schrobben overbodig.", "price": "79,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10430942, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 4 Premium Full Control", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool - voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Inclusief slanghaspel. Ideaal voor matige verontreiniging. Oppervlakteprestatie van 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "319,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10441943, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 4 Full Control Home", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool \u2013 voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Ideaal voor de incidentele reiniging van een gemiddelde vervuiling. Inclusief Home Kit. Oppervlakteprestatie van 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "339,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10430938, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 4 Full Control", "description": "Hogedrukreiniger met drukindicator op het hogedrukpistool \u2013 voor de juiste druk op elk oppervlak. Ideaal voor de incidentele reiniging van een gemiddelde vervuiling. Oppervlakteprestatie van 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "289,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10501457, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 3 Full Control Home T150", "description": "Perfect schoon rondom huis dankzij de Home Kit inclusief oppervlaktereiniger en reinigingsmiddelen. Het pistool van de K 3 Full Control Home hogedrukreiniger geeft het drukniveau aan.", "price": "209,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10501459, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 3 Full Control", "description": "Ideale hogedrukreiniger voor incidenteel gebruik bij lichte vervuiling. De K 3 Full Control geeft de druk aan op het pistool. Zo kunt u voor elk oppervlak de juiste druk instellen.", "price": "179,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10406424, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 3 Home", "description": "De K 3 Home hogedrukreiniger met Home Kit is ideaal voor incidenteel gebruik en voor de verwijdering van lichte vervuiling op bijvoorbeeld fietsen, tuinhekken en motorfietsen.", "price": "219,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10461899, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 2 Premium Full Control Home", "description": "De K 2 Premium Full Control Home hogedrukreiniger van K\u00e4rcher inclusief Home Kit en met gerichte drukregeling. Ideaal voor oppervlakken rondom het huis en op lichtere vervuiling.", "price": "179,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10464555, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 2 HOME T150", "description": "De K 2 Home op wieltjes is speciaal ontworpen voor incidenteel gebruik en lichte vervuiling. Dankzij de Home Kit houdt u met de hogedrukreiniger ook grotere oppervlakken rondom het huis eenvoudig schoon.", "price": "129,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10479573, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 2 Basic", "description": "De 'K2 Basic' hogedrukreiniger is ideaal voor incidenteel gebruik en verwijdering van normale vervuiling rondom de woning (bijv. fietsen, tuingereedschap, tuinmeubilair).", "price": "79,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10497774, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 7 Compact Home", "description": "Compact en handzaam: de hogedrukreiniger K 7 Compact met watergekoelde motor. Voor frequent gebruik en sterke vervuiling, bijvoorbeeld op straten, in zwembaden, op fietsen of grote auto's.", "price": "589,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10497770, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 5 Compact Home", "description": "De K5 Compact Home met watergekoelde motor neemt weinig ruimte in en kan comfortabel worden vervoerd. Hogedrukreiniger inclusief Home Kit met oppervlaktereiniger T 350 en steen- en gevelreiniger.", "price": "379,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10497773, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 5 Compact", "description": "Inclusief innovatieve slangopberging: de eenvoudig te vervoeren en op te bergen hogedrukreiniger K 5 Compact voor regelmatig gebruik bij middelzware vervuiling. Oppervlakteprestatie 40 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "329,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10497765, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 4 Compact Home", "description": "Eenvoudig te vervoeren en snel op te bergen: de K 4 Compact voor incidenteel gebruik bij middelzware vervuiling. Inclusief telescoopgreep en watergekoelde motor. Oppervlakteprestatie 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "289,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10497768, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 4 Compact", "description": "Eenvoudig te vervoeren en snel op te bergen: de K 4 Compact voor incidenteel gebruik bij middelzware vervuiling. Inclusief telescoopgreep en watergekoelde motor. Oppervlakteprestatie 30 m\u00b2/u.", "price": "249,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10472949, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 2 Battery Set", "description": "Kan overal worden ingezet waar er geen stopcontact beschikbaar is: De K2 hogedrukreiniger met accuaandrijving, inclusief 36 V li-ionaccu en oplader. Ideaal voor uiteenlopende toepassingen.", "price": "399,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:57"},
{"productid": 10472950, "category": "hogedrukreinigers", "name": "K 2 Battery", "description": "De hogedrukreiniger met accuaandrijving voor flexibel schoonmaken zonder stopcontact. Ideaal voor uiteenlopende toepassingen rondom het huis. Accu en oplader worden niet meegeleverd.", "price": "199,95", "timestamp": "18-08-2019 16:43:58"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `yield` category from CSV file to the `parse` using `request.meta`:

```
def start_requests(self):
    """Read keywords from keywords file amd construct the search URL"""

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/keywords.csv")) as search_keywords:
        for keyword in csv.DictReader(search_keywords):
            search_text=keyword["keyword"]
            category = keyword["keywordtype"]
            url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/{0}?page=1&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(
                search_text)
            # The meta is used to send our search text into the parser as metadata
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text, "category": category}) 

def parse(self, response):
    category = response.meta["category"]
    ...
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to have your `category` on next page you need to use `.meta` again:

```
    #Checking whether "isTruncated" is true (boolean), if so, next page will be triggered
if data["isTruncated"]:
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page),
        callback=self.parse,
        meta={'page': next_page, "category": category},
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @gangabass Your approach seems to be working to print out the correct category, however it interferes with the code which triggers the next page. It will only fetch the data from the first page of each product instead of all the pages of each product.

Comment: It seems to be crawling the first pages of all the different keywords, and then it tries to activate the next_page script to fetch the data from the other pages. It should be fetching all the pages of a certain keyword before going to the next keyword.

Comment: @Bamieschijf Sorry but I only showed you a way how to get `category` for the current product. All other code should be the same.

Comment: Thanks again @gangabass I just find it very weird that when I run the code without the category, it perfectly fetches all the pages from every product. When I add the code for the category it only fetches the data of the first page for each product. Looking at the code above, would you have any idea how that might happen? Do you think there is a better solution to all of this?

Comment: Hey @gangabass I edited my code to my current. I managed to find another solution to filter out the product category, I am fetching it from the product_URL. However, with my current code it wont fetch all the pages from the products other than the first one. This is because the product number "20035386" is in the 


url="https://www.kaercher.com/api/v1/products/search/shoppableproducts/partial/20035386?page={page}&size=8&isocode=nl-NL".format(page=next_page)


The number in there needs to be a variable for "search_text" or something, do you know how that is done?

Comment: @Bamieschijf sorry but you completely changed your original question and you still didn't show me a code with my solution that "doesn't work"...

Comment: hey @gangabass I think that must've been miscommunication. Your solution definitely does work. I edited the code to my current code. I also added the results as a JSON code. But somehow it is interfering with the part of code that parses through the pages because it only fetched the data on the first page of each product. If I remove the category it parses through all of the page's of the "Hogedrukreiniger" and only the first page of all the other's, this probably is because the URL with "next_page" has the number "20035386" in it. I don't know how to turn this into a variable.

Comment: @Bamieschijf obviously you have an error in you new code because my solution can't interference with your current logic. And you didn't show your edited code.

Comment: Hey @gangabass I added both the code with your working solution - and the code where the product category is being fetched by the URL -- to my question. Is this what you ment with my edited code?

Comment: Hey @gangabass Thank you very much for your solution! Now I just need to find a way to turn the number "20035386" into a variable in the URL where the page number gets adjusted. Once that is done, everything should be working :)